# Integrating Twilio with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twilio

Ok, well this is really doing my head in! I am trying to integrate Twilio with a Symfony2 site, and I found a bundle which apparently fits into the framework here: https://github.com/fridolin-koch/VreshTwilioBundle however, the main Twilio framework needed to be downloaded separately and the structure is not in keeping with Symfony2, in the sense that class names are different and there are no namespaces included. I installed the package via composer which seemed to work but I constantly get errors like this:

> The autoloader expected class "Vresh\TwilioBundle\Services_Twilio" to
>   be defined in file
>   "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/my_site_name/src/Vresh/TwilioBundle/Services/Twilio.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or
>   namespace probably has a typo.

And even with the correct namespace declared, I cannot get it to work. I feel that I'm going round in circles editing classes and changing code which I do not really know; if anyone else has managed to successfully integrated Twilio with Symfony2 I would appreciate any tips or help! Even the Twilio help desk know nothing about Symfony!

Thank you in advance
Michael

Comment: You should mark dmnptr's answer as correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We are successfully using Twilio. But we did not have to download it separately. `VreshTwilioBundle` is a wrapper that makes [`twilio/sdk`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) available inside of `Symfony`. All we did was:

- add this to the `composer.json`

  ```
  "require": {
      "vresh/twilio-bundle": "dev-master",
  }
  ```
- enable it in `AppKernel.php`

  ```
  $bundles = array(
      // ... other bundles
      new Vresh\TwilioBundle\VreshTwilioBundle(),
  );
  ```
- add configuration to `config.yml`

  ```
  vresh_twilio:
      #(Required) Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/user/account
      sid: 'XXXXXXXX'
      #(Required) Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/user/account
      authToken: 'YYYYYYYY'
      #(Optional, default: '2010-04-01') Twilio API version
      version: '2008-08-01'
      #(Optional, default: 1) Number of times to retry failed requests
      retryAttempts: 3
  ```

Basically, we just followed instructions for installing `VreshTwilioBundle`. This bundle adds `twilio/sdk` package as its requirement, so `twilio/sdk` is automatically downloaded when you run composer update.

That is all we had to do. Then, `twilio/sdk` is available as a service through container:

```
    $twilio = $this->get('twilio.api');
```